# how do i use AJAX in jQuery on multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
(function($) {
    $('.myclass').each(function(){
        $(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "myPHP.php?app",
                method: 'GET',
                complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    var response = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
                    $('.myclass').html(response.app);
                }
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

i have multiple instances of myclass and I want each instance to be replaced with response.app but it doesnt happen.

What am i missing?

Comment: can you get response correctly?

Comment: yes i can. it responds and works but only for the first element .myclass

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your code, on every response from the server, all of your `.myclass` will be modified. You could try something like this:

```
$('.myclass').each(function() {
  var $elem = $(this); // <-------------- Save the element for the ajax callback
  $.ajax({
    url: "myPHP.php?app",
    method: 'GET',
    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
      var response = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
      $elem.html(response.app); // <-------------- Use it
    }
  });
});
```

By the way, the requested URL seems to be the same for each call, with no specific parameter. If that's the case in your real code, then you only need to make one request (no `.each()`), and apply the result to all of your elements:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "myPHP.php?app",
    method: 'GET',
    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
      var response = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
      $('.myclass').html(response.app);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery´s html function handles the replacement off all occurrence of myclass
so you just have to make the ajax call and pass the response

```
$.ajax({
  url: "myPHP.php?app",
  method: 'GET'
}).done(function(response){
  $('.myclass').html(response.app)
});
```